# How to send checkbox value using jquery.ajax from Bootstrap modal?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, checkbox, flask-wtforms

I have a form with a checkbox on a webpage pop-up modal using flask/bootstrap/jquery. I want to post the form without a page refresh, so I'm using jquery.ajax. The form works fine and my flask app receives all the data fields it's supposed to *except* the checkbox value doesn't change no matter what I've tried.

I fully understand that with an HTML post request, if a checkbox is unchecked it doesn't appear in the payload at all, and that you can tell it's been checked by testing for its presence. But apparently that's not the behavior with an ajax post, because it sends the checkbox value every time, checked or not, and it doesn't change from one state to the other, checked or unchecked.

Here's code snips:
(flask) forms.py

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators = [InputRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators = [InputRequired()])
    company = StringField('Company/Organization')
    cell_number = StringField('Cell No')
    email = StringField('Your Email', validators = [Email()])
    opt_in = BooleanField()
    form_message = TextAreaField('Message', validators = [InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Send')
```

(html) index.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p class="text-white">
    {{ form.first_name(size=12, placeholder='First name') }}&nbsp&nbsp
    {{ form.last_name(size=16, placeholder='Last name') }} <br><br>
    {{ form.company(size=16, placeholder='Company/Organization') }} &nbsp&nbsp
    {{ form.email(size=20, placeholder='email address') }} <br><br>
    {{ form.opt_in(id='opt_in', type='checkbox') }} I want to receive a bi-weekly "Website Tips & Tricks" email newsletter<br>
    {{ form.cell_number(size=12, placeholder='Cellphone') }} &nbsp(if you want a text-message reply) <br><br>            
    {{ form.form_message(cols=58, rows=6, placeholder='Enter your message') }} <br><br>
    {{ form.submit() }} &nbsp&nbsp <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br>
    </p>  
 </form>
```

(embedded javascript)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

$('form').on('submit', function(event) {

    var option = 'n'
    if ($('#opt_in').is(":checked"))
      {
        option = 'y';
      } else 
        { option = 'n';
      }  

    $.ajax({
        data : {
            first_name : $('#first_name').val(),
            last_name : $('#last_name').val(),
            company : $('#company').val(),
            email : $('#email').val(),
            opt_in : $('option'),      // $('#opt_in').val(),
            cell_number : $('#cell_number').val(),
            form_message : $('#form_message').val()
            },
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/contactform'
          })
      .done(function(data) {
        if (data.error) {
            $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
            $('#successAlert').hide();
            }
        else {
            $('#successAlert').text(data.name).show();
            $('#errorAlert').hide();
            }
          });
        event.preventDefault();
      });
  });
</script>
```

(flask) routes.py

```
@app.route('/contactform', methods=['POST'])
    def contactform():
    first_name = request.form['first_name']
    last_name = request.form['last_name']
    company = request.form['company']
    email = request.form['email']
    permission = request.form['opt_in']
    cell_number = request.form['cell_number']
    form_message = request.form['form_message']

    email_body = (f"<html><body>A new contact-form submission has arrived:<br><br>"
    f"First name: {first_name}<br>"
    f"Last name: {last_name}<br>"
    f"Company: {company}<br><br>"
    f"Email: {email}<br>"
    f"Opt-in: {permission}<br><br>"
    f"Cell number: {cell_number}<br><br>"
    f"Message: {form_message}<br>"
    f"Form list: {str(request.form)}"
    f"</body></html>")
```

You'll see the if/else at the top of the JS snippet. That's my latest of several attempts to hack out a solution. In the "/contactform" endpoint from routes.py, you'll also note I'm printing out the contents of the "request.form" object to see what flask is actually receiving from the ajax post.

Since the form works properly in every way other than the checkbox state, there's some little thing I'm missing. Does anyone know what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move `event.preventDefault()` to the top of your submit handler
2. Change `opt_in : $('option')` to `opt_in : option`

Comment: Well, that seems to have worked! Many, many thanks! I thought I had tried referencing "option" as a plain JS variable, but I guess not. Unless I tried it but with the 'preventDefault' call at the bottom and that was part of the problem. Since the form was working fine except for the checkbox with that call at the bottom, why was it necessary to move it to the top to get the checkbox to work?

Comment: Threw it in for good measure. It doesn't make a heap of difference but if an error was thrown before it, the form wouldn't prevent default behaviour. Best practice to invoke preventDefault immediately if the handler doesn't expect to resume default behaviour.